# Is it better to have several different tables for similar objects, or one big table?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, orm

I have an optimisation problem for my tables :

I have `Items` that can have a `price` by one, by ten and by hundred.

Right now i have three tables for that :

```
class Prix_x1(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    prix = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    saved_at = models.DateTimeField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Prix_x10(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    prix = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    saved_at = models.DateTimeField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Prix_x100(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    prix = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    saved_at = models.DateTimeField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But often  i need to check which of these prices is the lowest on a per unit basis. So i have to check each price table for each Item every time i need to do that.
So my question is : Is it a better way to optimse that ?

For exemple, is it better to have one big table `Price` with a field `number_of_unit` that can take 1, 10 or 100 as value ?

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have a spot for each price in the model:

```
class Prix(models.Model):
def __str__(self):
    return self.item.name

prix_x1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
prix_x10 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
prix_x100 = models.IntegerField(null=True)

saved_at = models.DateTimeField()
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Why i didn't think of this, so simple ahah ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think is better have one table

```
class Prix(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    prix = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    prix_x = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    saved_at = models.DateTimeField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

save and increment prix and prix_x